# How would I make a 3D checkerboard array

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

I am using unity to try to make a 3D checkerboard inside a 3d array. I have not found a single other place answering this question.

If possible, doing it in 3 nesting for loops would be preferred, that is how 2d checkerboards are usually made.

Comment: 2 nesteded loops the size of your checkerboard and then create black and white panes alternating?

Comment: Referring to "inside a 3d array", it is a 3d array of what? Do you have GameObjects or you would like to say get 0 for white and 1 for black and get an array of ints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script that generates a 3D checkerboard in the Start method so that you may drag it to an object in the scene and follow the steps. 
The logic in the nested loops checks whether the sum of the indices i and j are odd or even. Then the code alternates between black and white tiles by checking whether the index k, which corresponds to the height, is odd or even.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Checkerboard3D : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        // This is the container for the checkerboard
        List<List<List<GameObject>>> Checkerboard = new List<List<List<GameObject>>>();
        // Create primitive, reference tiles
        GameObject CheckerBoardWhiteTile = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        GameObject CheckerBoardBlackTile = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        CheckerBoardBlackTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black;
        // Rows, columns, and height can be parameters to the function
        Int32 rows = 10;
        Int32 columns = 10;
        Int32 height = 10;
        for(Int32 i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            Checkerboard.Add(new List<List<GameObject>>());
            for(Int32 j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                Checkerboard[i].Add(new List<GameObject>());
                for(Int32 k = 0; k < height; k++)
                {
                    GameObject objectToAdd = null;
                    // The position is set this way since Y is up in Unity
                    Vector3 position = new Vector3(i, k, j);
                    if(((i + j) % 2) == 0)
                    {
                        if(k % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            objectToAdd = GameObject.Instantiate(CheckerBoardWhiteTile, position, Quaternion.identity);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            objectToAdd = GameObject.Instantiate(CheckerBoardBlackTile, position, Quaternion.identity);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(k % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            objectToAdd = GameObject.Instantiate(CheckerBoardBlackTile, position, Quaternion.identity);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            objectToAdd = GameObject.Instantiate(CheckerBoardWhiteTile, position, Quaternion.identity);
                        }
                    }
                    // Thus, you can access elements of the checkerboards by Checkerboard[i][j][k]
                    Checkerboard[i][j].Add(objectToAdd); 
                }
            }
        }
        // To clean up the primitive GameObjects we instantiated in the beginning
        Destroy(CheckerBoardWhiteTile);
        Destroy(CheckerBoardBlackTile);
    }
}
```

If you would like to add scale, you need to change the `Vector3 position` according to your scale, and provide a `Vector3 scale` while you are instantiating the `objectToAdd GameObject`.

The result of this script to generate a 10x10x10 checkerboard is as follows:
[image]

Comment: That helped a lot, thank you! I was able to put it into my code and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I am glad that this has worked for you, happy coding! In StackOverflow, you may consider upvoting an answer if you found it to be helpful. Thus, other people would see the most useful answers on top.